# Select combination of rows based on specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations

I have this table:

```
WeekID  ISModelled  ProductID   Units   Value
1       MODEL       123         0       0
2       EPOS        123         0       0
2       MODEL       123         100     50
3       IMPUTE      987         100     50
4       MODEL       123         100     50
4       EPOS        987         100     50
4       EPOS        123         100     50
5       EPOS        987         0       0
5       MODEL       987         100     50
```

And I want to get this possible combination out of it:

```
WeekID  ISModelled  ProductID   Units   Value
2       EPOS        123         0       0
2       MODEL       123         100     50
5       EPOS        987         0       0
5       MODEL       987         100     50
```

I want to select on `ProductID`, by `WeekID`, any combination where the `ISModelled` column with "EPOS" has a value of 0 in the `Units` and the `Value` columns and where the `IsModelled` column with Model has any value above 0 in the `Units` and `Value` columns.

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: Why only 2 for MODEL in result set?

Comment: Because in WeekID=1 there is only 1 Model Result with no EPOS (so I dont want these) and in WeekID=4 ProductID 123 with EPOS has value above 0, and I dont want these either

Comment: @MartaLopes, I have updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a matching pairs problem with unpivot with a possibility of no matchs, or multiple matchs - allocating a row number should help with this
 possibility.

```
  /*> drop table if exists t;
   /*> create table t (
   /*> WeekID int, ISModelled varchar(10), ProductID int,  Units int,  Value int);
   /*> insert into t values
   /*> (1  ,     'MODEL'   ,    123   ,      0    ,   0),
   /*> (2  ,     'EPOS'    ,    123   ,      0    ,   0),
   /*> (2  ,     'MODEL'   ,    123   ,      100  ,   50),
   /*> (3  ,     'IMPUTE'  ,    987   ,      100  ,   50),
   /*> (4  ,     'MODEL'   ,    123   ,      100  ,   50),
   /*> (4  ,     'EPOS'    ,    987   ,      100  ,   50),
   /*> (4  ,     'EPOS'     ,   123   ,      100  ,   50),
   /*> (5  ,     'EPOS'    ,    987   ,      0    ,   0),
   /*> (5  ,     'MODEL'   ,    987   ,      100  ,   50);
   /*> */
MariaDB [sandbox]> select S.* from
    -> (
    -> select t.ISModelled Smodelled,
    -> t.* ,
    ->  if(t.WeekID <> @pw ,@rne:=1,@rne:=@rne+1) rne,
    ->  @pw:=t.weekid
    -> from   (select @rne:=0,@pw:=0) rn,t
    -> where  t.ismodelled  = 'EPOS' and t.units = 0 and t.Value = 0
    -> order  by t.weekid
    -> ) s
    -> join
    -> (
    -> select t.ISModelled Mmodelled,
    ->  t.* ,
    ->  if(t.WeekID <> @pw ,@rne:=1,@rne:=@rne+1) rne,
    ->  @pw:=t.weekid
    -> from   (select @rne:=0,@pw:=0) rn,t
    -> where  t.ismodelled   = 'MODEL' and t.units > 0 and t.Value > 0
    -> order  by t.weekid
    -> ) t on t.weekid = s.weekid and t.rne = s.rne and t.productid = s.productid
    -> where Smodelled = 'EPOS'
    -> union ALL
    -> select T.* from
    -> (
    -> select t.ISModelled Emodelled,
    -> t.* ,
    ->  if(t.WeekID <> @pw ,@rne:=1,@rne:=@rne+1) rne,
    ->  @pw:=t.weekid
    -> from   (select @rne:=0,@pw:=0) rn,t
    -> where  t.ismodelled  = 'EPOS' and t.units = 0 and t.Value = 0
    -> order  by t.weekid
    -> ) s
    -> join
    -> (
    -> select t.ISModelled Mmodelled,
    -> t.* ,
    ->  if(t.WeekID <> @pw ,@rne:=1,@rne:=@rne+1) rne,
    ->  @pw:=t.weekid
    -> from   (select @rne:=0,@pw:=0) rn,t
    -> where  t.ismodelled   = 'MODEL' and t.units > 0 and t.Value > 0
    -> order  by t.weekid
    -> ) t on t.weekid = s.weekid and t.rne = s.rne and t.productid = s.productid
    -> where Mmodelled = 'MODEL'
    -> ORDER BY WEEKID,ISMODELLED,RNE
    ->
    ->
    ->
    -> ;
+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+---------------+
| Smodelled | WeekID | ISModelled | ProductID | Units | Value | rne  | @pw:=t.weekid |
+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+---------------+
| EPOS      |      2 | EPOS       |       123 |     0 |     0 |    1 |             2 |
| MODEL     |      2 | MODEL      |       123 |   100 |    50 |    1 |             2 |
| EPOS      |      5 | EPOS       |       987 |     0 |     0 |    1 |             5 |
| MODEL     |      5 | MODEL      |       987 |   100 |    50 |    1 |             5 |
+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-------+-------+------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Verbosity of your answer. If you edit the post, I will remove the downvote (no possibility to do it without your edit). Your query does the job, but it's complicated.

Comment: @Grzegorz Górkiewicz I may have over complicated the question - on the other hand you may have over simplified. Consider the case where  there are 2 MODELs in weekid 5 which match the selection criteria the end result using my solution would be EPOS,MODEL matched on productid using your solution it would be EPOS,MODEL,MODEL (and it wouldn't care which productid it finds for MODEL) - I don't know which is the correct outcome from the question.

Comment: Let's wait for the OP's feedback. If you edit your post, I will remove the downvote. It is not technically possible without your edit.

Comment: I concur with @P.Salmon; I believe that rows should be matched/paired by WeekID *and* by ProductID.  Unfortunately, with the OP's rating being so low, I find it unlikely that it will be categorically clarified.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here provide some valid options, but there is another ANSI-SQL pattern that works for this.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        WeekID,
        ProductID
    FROM
        yourTable
    WHERE
           (IsModelled = 'MODEL' AND Units > 0 AND Value > 0)
        OR (IsModelled = 'EPOS'  AND Units = 0 AND Value = 0)
    GROUP BY
        WeekID,
        ProductID
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT IsModelled) = 2
)
    matchingPairs
        ON  matchingPairs.WeekID    = yourTable.WeekID
        AND matchingPairs.ProductID = yourTable.ProductID
WHERE
    yourTable.IsModelled IN ('MODEL', 'EPOS')
ORDER BY
    WeekID,
    ProductID,
    IsModelled
```

This is actually functionally similar to the answer that uses `EXISTS` with a correlated-sub-query.  Performance, however, should be better due using only one sub-query, and that sub-query not being correlated *(which MySQL often has poor performance with)*.

It also benefits from having less repeated code and *(in my opinion)* clearer intention *(readability)*.

***Note:*** I have assumed that `(WeekId, ProductID, IsModelled)` is unique.

Comment: all the order by items are ambiguous and the solution doesn't produce a distinct matching pair - for example of you add another weekid 5 MODEL 987 the result is EPOS,MODEL,MODEL

Comment: @P.Salmon There are no ORDER BY clauses in there that affect the logic.  What is ambiguous?  , Also, I specifically note the assumption about uniqueness (If it is unique, your example becomes a constraint violation).